# How to change Tez job name when running query in HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

When I submit a Hive SQL using Tez like below:

```
hive (default)> select count(*) from simple_data;
```

In Resource Manager UI the job name shows something like `HIVE-9d1906a2-25dd-4a7c-9ea3-bf651036c7eb` Is there a way to change the job name to`my_job_nam`?

If I am not using Tez and running the job in MR, I can set the job name using `set mapred.job.name`.

Are there any Tez parameters I need to set, to change the job name?

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: MR will run a new job for each query; but TEZ will try to maintain its "session" open to avoid de-allocating and re-allocating YARN containers all the time. So your question is rather *how to set the current (or future) TEZ session name*. See http://fr.hortonworks.com/blog/introducing-tez-sessions/  >> Unfortunately HIVE is not aware of how TEZ works and has no specific parameter for that...

Comment: By the way: there is a long-standing request to support **custom tags** in YARN and TEZ jobs (especially for OOZIE job management) but these JIRAs don't show much progress, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TEZ-909

Comment: Thank you very much Samson for the info.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "set hiveconf hive.query.name=myjobname"
But you will be able to see the name only in TEZ view. Not in Yarn.
See the link below:
https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/5309/how-to-set-tez-job-name.html
I`m looking into this issue also. If I find the solution I update the question.

Answer (score 1):

Got this figured out. Using the property `hive.session.id` the name could be changed. Below is an example.

```
hive --hiveconf hive.session.id=test_$(date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S') \
      -e "select month, max(sale) from simple_data group by month;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Good question. There is a JIRA for Hive on Spark for a very similar thing that you're asking: [HIVE-12811](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-12811) - you could use spark.app.name there; landing in Hive 2.1.

Can't find anything specific for Hive on Tez.. perhaps somebody needs to submit a Hive jira/patch similar to Hive-12811 but for Tez.

Answer (score -1):

set hive.query.name="test_query";

Will work in hive with TEZ

Answer (score -3):

set mapred.job.name = more helpful name

Comment: The original question already notes that as a possibility if not using Tez, but wants a solution using Tez.