# Job name for Tez job in beeline and view it in YARN

Tags: hadoop, hiveql, hadoop-yarn, beeline, apache-tez

I'm using Beeline and like to set a specific name for a TEZ job, like I use `mapreduce.job.name` for a MapReduce job. I tried `hive.query.name`, but it doesn't make any difference in `yarn application -list`.

Some say we can view the name only in TEZ UI, but I only have access to YARN. Please help me.

I have a load script in Beeline with TEZ as execution engine running now,
when I'm trying to see the active applications in YARN with `yarn application -list` command, I get something like `HIVE-<UUID>` as the job name.

I would like to change it to more readable.

I can do the same if the execution engine is MR with `SET mapreduce.job.name = myJobName` command.

I want similar command for TEZ engine, as I already said `SET hive.query.name=myJobName` is not seems to be working.

Comment: It would be nice if you can clarify your problem. You can read StackOverflow guidelines to understand how you can make your question more verbose.

Comment: @GopalYadav I have explained it. Please see.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Tez job name when running query in HIVE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33422749/how-to-change-tez-job-name-when-running-query-in-hive)

Answer (score 0):

Try also to set session id:

```
set hive.session.id=myJobName;
```

Or start hive with hiveconf parameter:

```
hive --hiveconf hive.session.id=myJobName -f "myscript.hql"
```

Comment: It might be the case that it is [not possible to set YARN RM application names for for Hive TEZ queries using hive.session.id property](https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/245018/unable-to-set-yarn-rm-application-names-for-hive-t.html) because *"When running it from Beeline, HiveServer2 overrides this property and sets it to default session ID"* so *"The current method of customizing the Yarn Application name during runtime works only with Hive CLI"*.

Comment: I have tried that too... That doesn't works, @U880D I have even tried hive.session.id with hive (not with beeline). It didn't work, any thoughts on this?
hive -e "set hive.execution.engine=tez; SET hiveconf hive.query.name=myjobname; set mapreduce.job.name=myjobname; set hive.session.id=myjobname; query I used inside the script.

Comment: As mentioned in my comment and within the comment of question [How to change Tez job name when running query in HIVE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33422749/how-to-change-tez-job-name-when-running-query-in-hive), it seems that it is still not implemented.